# Can gentle repose be used on a zombie to preserve it?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, undead

The text for [*gentle repose*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/gentle-repose) states the following for the purposes of targeting:

> You touch a corpse or other remains.

Last I checked, zombies were shambling corpses, so can *gentle repose* work on zombies to keep them from rotting more?

I'm looking for an answer to this from a player's perspective.

Comment: Is your issue that your DM has a concern (or a player of yours) with their zombies rotting flesh? I'm not sure if you are trying to solve a specific problem or if this is just theory craft.

Comment: As a player, I'd like to have some nice looking zombies following me around. But firstly, I need to see whether I can even cast this spell on the zombies! If I get positive answers to this, I'll ask whether Animate Dead can be used on gentle repose'd zombies to refresh them, so to speak.

Comment: Pretty sure that is your question, can you let me know if it's different?

Comment: Poop, I sped read that question and assumed it was asking whether a fungal spores druid could raise a gentle repose'd creature. I might edit that question to clarify what it's asking at the end then.